# Iterating over set of lists to find highest average in Python

Tags: python, list, average

How to create function which iterates over each county, calculating voter turnout percentage?

```
class County:  
    def __init__(self, init_name, init_population, init_voters) :  
        self.name = init_name  
        self.population = init_population  
        self.voters = init_voters   

def highest_turnout(data) :  

    100 * (self.voters / self.population)

allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)  
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)  
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)  
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)  
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)  
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)  
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)  
data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]
```

Comment: do you mean the `highest_turnout` is the method of the class `County`?

Comment: yes, just not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `County` is defined correctly.
However, function `county` is not correct.

When passing data in the function `highest_turnout`, you have to first calculate the percentage of voters in the first `County` of the list - it is positioned at `data[0]`.
Then we set “highest” to be the country name of the 1st `County`, we assume that the 1st in the `data` list is the highest one we have seen.

Next, we use a `for` loop to start iterating over all the `County` objects in the list `data` in order to pass in each `County` object.

The variable `pct` gives us the percentage of voters in the `County` that is running in the current step. The `if` function compares it to the highest percentage stored in the variable `pct`. If the new percentage is higher than `pct` (returns True), we update the highest percentage variable `pct` and hence update the county name.

```
def highest_turnout(data) :

  highest_pct = data[0].voters / data[0].population
  highest = data[0].name

  for county in data :
    pct = county.voters / county.population
    if pct > highest_pct :
      highest_pct = pct
      highest = county.name
```